# Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.1'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, bing-ads-api

I'm trying to update Bing Ads SDK to version 12.13.5.  I am using Visual Studio 2013.  Nuget version is 2.12.0.817.  When I try to update, I get the following error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I tried installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.0.0 (latest version) and get the same error.

I also tried targeting .NET version 4.6.1 and 4.5.2 and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who may have this problem, the solution was to manually add a package entry 
 for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.1 to packages.config.  This allowed the Bing Ads SDK package to update successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [docs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/2.1.1), your platform needs to be **.NETStandard 2.0** or **.Net Core 2.1**.

The libraries that target `.NETStandard2.0`, means any `.NET Core` app that is compatible with the .NET Standard 2.0 can use them, regardless of the .NET SDK they are using.

Comment: .NETStandard 2.0 is listed on my project's references tab.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: The error indicates your target platform is .Net  framework 4.7.2. Though you can change it to Net Core from project properties.

Comment: I should not have to change the target from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET Core in order to install this package.  4.7.2 includes .NET Standard 2.0.  I have another project that also targets 4.7.2 that installed the package without an error.  I have compared the 2 projects and haven't found a difference that explains why it installed  in one and not the other.  But I did notice that there is no Microsoft.Extensions.Logging folder in the packages directory of the project where the upgrade was successful.